# Ordering a list in-place by two properties

Tags: c#, list, class, reorderlist

I have a class with two properties, Name and Position.
I would like to order the list with this class by Position, and the elements with the same position should be ordered by Name. I am working on a static list, so I would like to work in-place.

So far I managed to order the list by one property:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => x.Position.CompareTo(y.Position));
```

this code is working and I have the list ordered by Position, but I don't know how to implement the second part. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765068/ordering-a-list-by-two-properties-parentid-and-childid) question, but I don't understand the answer.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked to is correct. The key in sorting by multiple values is that the secondary property only matters if the primaries are equal. A psuedocode implementation of your sort comparison might be:

```
compare x and y position
if they differ, return order
else compare name, return order
```

On the `Sort` method, the code following the `(x,y)=>` must return 0 if the items are equal, a negative number if the first should be before the second, and a positive number if the second should come before the first. The `CompareTo` method will return -1, 0, or 1 based on these cases and its arguments. Since you need to compare two different properties, you need two calls to `CompareTo`. If you decided to add them together, you could have a case like this:

- x.position < y.position (compare returns -1)
- x.name > y.name (compare returns 1)
- result 0, items are considered equal, where your rules
  clearly say x should come first in this case.

To solve this issue, we need to make sure the Name comparison only matters when the positions are equal. Since `CompareTo` only returns -1, 0, or 1, if we multiply the position result by 2 (or any larger number) then the Name comparison will only change the result if the positions are equal. (Because `-2 + 1 = -1` and `2 - 1 = 1`)

So using the method in your original linked answer, your code would be something like:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => 
    2 * x.Position.CompareTo(y.Position) 
    + x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

Comment: @Hamma: I hope it helps you understand why the multiplication exists. You should also consider Rene Hilgers' answer. It does create a new list, but unless you are doing this sort many times and your list is fairly large and you are trying to avoid GCs, you probably don't need to worry about creating a new list for this sort.

Comment: I'm working with different threads that access and modify the list simultaneously through locks, so my concern is to make the operations as quickly and as effectively as possible.
I understand the multiplication is to give a hierarchy to the two properties.

Answer (score 8):

I would use "OrderBy" and "ThenBy":

```
  IEnumerable<Person> orderedPersons = persons.OrderBy(item => item.Position)
            .ThenBy(item => item.Name);
```

Comment: This is by far the most reliable way to do that.

Comment: This is the simplest way to sort by 2 properties, but does require creating a new list, which OP did not want to do. (though there aren't many reasons that working in place the list would be necessary - save for performance if the list is very large)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = list.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList();
list.Sort((x, y) => x.Position.CompareTo(y.Position));
```

Comment: This implicitly relies on the underlying sort algorithm to not change the order of equal items.